# EventRelations not showing up on Event with multiple attendees

Tags: apex, event

So I have a piece of code that takes contactIds and creates EventRelations for an event during a piece of Apex code.

```
//looping through each contact
EventRelation er = new EventRelation();
er.EventId = eventId;
er.RelationId = contactId;
er.isInvitee = true;
insert er;
```

This works and inserts into tables; I confirmed it via the developer console and the Event Relation table. My main issue is it does not show up in the actual UI of the event in the "Name" field. Some debugging items I've already tried:

- I can edit the Name field to hold multiple contacts in the Salesforce UI, so I know that I can have multiple contacts there
- I have created an event with no "WhoId" through Apex, and then retroactively added in multiple contacts, and they have shown up in the EventRelations table.

Any sort of help with this would be appreciated, not sure what I am missing. Every example I've looked at recently is doing it this way (setting one WhoID, then creating EventRelations for everyone else). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by adding the following flags

```
er.isInvitee = false; //(this used to be true)
er.isParent = true;
er.isWhat = false;
```

I personally was setting the WhoId on event creation and then adding the rest of the attendees like this, but this would likely work for all of them. Hope this helps someone.